# How do I implement an AccordeonControl inside GroupedListView? (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am fairly new to Xamarin.Forms and WPF in general. So currently there are no ViewModels in use, because I have just recently read about MVVM and will change it later on. I hope this doesn't make much difference for now.

We want to implement an AccordeonControl inside a grouped ListView ([Sketch can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qechfpo8y4va3fv/sketch.png?dl=0)).
When clicking on a RaceEvent the races should be expanded.

I have implemented the GroupedListView (without accordeon) like follows:

### ListView.xaml

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.Height>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <OnPlatform.iOS>
              32
            </OnPlatform.iOS>
          </OnPlatform>
        </ViewCell.Height>

        <Label Text="{Binding Path=Key,   StringFormat='{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           YAlign="Center"
           XAlign="Center"
           FontSize="32"/>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <ContentView Padding="10,0,0,0">
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               YAlign="Center"
               FontSize="28"/>
          </ContentView>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Grouped ListViews apparently require a class which contains a Key and inherits from ObservableCollection, so I made a generic class:

### Grouping.cs

```
class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection
{
   public K Key { get; set; }

   public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
   {
      Key = key;
      foreach (var item in items)
        this.Items.Add(item);
   }
}
```

### In the code behind I generate an IEnumerable using LINQ:

##
    private void UpdateListView(IEnumerable events)
    {
        Items.Clear();

```
    // Order events by dates and group by dates. The result is an      IEnumerable of type Grouping.
    var sorted = from raceEvent in events
                 orderby raceEvent.DateTime descending
                 group raceEvent by raceEvent.DateTime into grp
                 select new Grouping<DateTime, IRaceEvent>(grp.Key, grp);

    foreach (var item in sorted)
        Items.Add(item);
 }
```

How can I extend this code?

Thanks in advance

Niklas Rammerstorfer

Comment: Xamarin Forms doesn't include an Accordian control, you will have to write your own.  And WPF and Xamarin Forms are completely separate technologies, they just both happen to support XAML.

Comment: Well, thank you for the information that WPF is a complte separate technology. The other information was actually just a summary of my problem o.O. I know that I have to implement my own, but I don't know how to do that. That's the whole reason for my question.

Comment: Try this: http://www.compliancestudio.io/blog/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview